# Common registry area for x32 and x64

Tags: c#, c++, registry

I need to find a location in the registry that is common to both the x32 (windows xp), and x64 (Windows 7).

The x32 (c++) application writes an encrypted string to the registry, and the x64 (c#) application needs to read and decode it.

What i am looking for is a common registry area that will allow both system to read this area.

Comment: What you need to watch fr is the virtual store.

Comment: This is [well documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Just pick one that's shared or not listed.

Comment: Machine wide, or user wide?

Answer (score 1):

The canonical location is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\<companyname>\<appname>\`. Your keys, your rules.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple that immediately come to mind: `HKEY_USERS` and `HKEY_MACHINE`. But don't just find some place to put them, you need to build your own tree under one of those keys. I would recommend `HKEY_USERS` because that's a good place for general application settings (e.g. Windows Media Player makes vast use of that key).

Further, the architecture will have no effect on the registry. At least I can't think of a single instance where that's true.

Comment: `HKEY_MACHINE` is definitely out. Applications should not run as Administrator. HKLM is for installers, drivers, etc.